# Programa PHP que me cargue un número aleatorio y ese numero no cambie al enviar formulario

Tags: php, formularios, random

He creado un código PHP que me genera un número aleatorio entre 1 y 100 con la función rand y lo he guardado en una variable de sesión. En el index tengo un formulario que me pide un número a través de un input y al clicar sobre el botón enviar el formulario se envía a sí mismo mediante $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']. Mi problema es que al darle al botón enviar se cambia el número aleatorio generado en el otro documento PHP y quiero que ese número se mantenga constante y no varíe al enviar el formulario.

El código que tengo actualmente es este:

```
<?php

session_start();

$aleatorio = rand(1,100);

$_SESSION['numeroaleatorio'] = $aleatorio;


?>
```

```
<?php

require('numeroaleatorio.php');

echo "<h3> ADIVINA EL NUMERO </h3>

<form  method='post' action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."'>
Introduce el numero: <input type='text' name='numero'/> <br>
<input type='submit' name='enviar' value='Enviar'/>
</form>";

$numero = ($_POST['numero']);

if(empty($numero)){
    echo "Debes introducir un numero";
}elseif($numero < $_SESSION['numeroaleatorio']){
    echo 'El numero que buscas es mayor.';
}elseif($numero > $_SESSION['numeroaleatorio']){
    echo 'El numero que buscas es menor.';
}elseif($numero == $_SESSION['numeroaleatorio']){
    echo 'Numero correcto';
}

echo $_SESSION['numeroaleatorio'];

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Cada que incluyes el archivo `numeroaleatorio.php` se está sobreescribiendo la variable de sesión. Puedes poner un condicional para que solo asigne la variable si no existe

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["numeroaleatorio"])){
   $aleatorio = rand(1,100);

   $_SESSION['numeroaleatorio'] = $aleatorio;
}
```